# How do I remove water marks / stains from a marble countertop?

Tags: cleaning

Our marble bathroom countertop has a few problem areas - most are water stains, but a few are marks on the surface, and it's hard to determine the source.

Looking for best tips/tricks to treat & clean the surface.  I'm not certain that it was ever 'sealed' properly as we weren't the initial owners.  Is it recommended to regularly seal or treat marble counters?

Answer (score 4):

The water 'stains' on the surface of marble are often etching from acidic chemical reactions. There are [special](http://www.janilink.com/product_info.php?products_id=3539) [marble](http://www.drillspot.com/products/510906/tough_guy_2wed7_granite_and_marble_liquid_stone_polish?s=1) [polishing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HJ9CAS) compounds that you can buff the surface with to restore it.

Comment: I cleaned houses for a while in college.  We made people with marble counters and showers provide their own marble polish, and most bought something similar to those Doresoom linked to.  It's expensive, but anything else risks causing further damage.  I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 2):

If its a stain, you could try oxygen bleach: [www.stainsolver.com](http://www.stainsolver.com). Acorrding to the FAQ, its safe to use on marble.