# How do I get a yellow stain out of a marble sink?

Tags: repair, bathroom, sink

I saw a [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/how-do-i-remove-water-marks-stains-from-a-marble-countertop) but it didn't give me an answer that helped. I recently began to replace the faucets and spout in one of out bathroom sinks. The marble that was covered by the previous chrome faucets is discolored and my new faucets don't have a large enough diameter to cover the stain. Here is a photo of what it looks like:

[image: Stain around hole in sink]

I've tried marble polish, bartender's friend, and a stripper for marble to no avail. What can I do to get rid of this stain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is real marble, you are unfortunately stuck with what you got. once a stain is set in unsealed marble, it is next to impossible to remove. The only method is to mechanically repolish the surface, removing material until you get below the stain. Marble is a very porous material.  Sorry,,,,,,,